# What if I write static public void instead of public static void in c sharp?

Tags: c#

Since I'm new to OOPS concept,What if I write static public void instead of public static void in c sharp? Will that make any difference?

Answer (score 4):

The [C# language specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-334_5th_edition_december_2017.pdf) defines a method header in chapter 15.6.1 as

> method-header:
> attributes<sub>opt</sub>   method-modifiers<sub>opt</sub>   partial<sub>opt</sub>   return-type   member-name   type-parameter-list<sub>opt</sub>
> (   formal-parameter-list<sub>opt</sub>   )   type-parameter-constraints-clauses<sub>opt</sub>

and

> method-modifiers: 
> method-modifier 
> method-modifiers   method-modifier

So the order is

- Attributes (`[Something]`) must go first
- Modifers come next (`new public protected internal private static virtual sealed override abstract extern`) in any order (**that's what you're asking about**)
- `partial` must be before the return type
- the return type is before the method
- the return type generics (`<Something>`) comes before parameters
- parameters in parentheses
- and a `where` clause last

Answer (score 3):

- It won’t make any difference as long as your method name comes last and the return type of your method comes second last.
- It's generally a best practice to put the access specifier (i.e public, private, protected) at the start

Answer (score 1):

No, this is pure standard coding guidelines, the generated code will be exactly the same.
The general guideline is to put the visibility keyword first.

I suggest you to use the StyleCop analyzer in order to be used to efficient, standard guidelines :
https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers